# Не получается создать адаптер

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь создать адаптер для того чтобы заполнить единственный listView.

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
                                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
                                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.dialogs, R.id.listView, Dialogs);

                                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                            }
                        });
```

Не компилится, ругается на эти аргументы:

```
(this, R.layout.dialogs, R.id.listView, Dialogs)
```

P.S. Dialogs - массив String глобальный

Что я делаю не так?
Ошибка: cannot resolve constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы получаете сообщение *Cannot resolve constructor* - невозможно определить конструктор, [самое время посмотреть](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#pubctors), какие конструкторы вообще имеет `ArrayAdapter`:

`ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource)`

- где:
  *context* - контекст,
  *resource* - ID ресурса с разметкой для одного айтема в списке,  вида *R.layout.item*.

`ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)`

- где:
  *context* - контекст,
  *resource* - ссылка на ресурс с разметкой для айтема вида *R.layout.item*,
  *textViewResourceId* - ID ресурса, указывающий на `TextView` в разметке айтема, в который будут выводиться данные, вида *R.id.textView*.

`ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)`

- где:
  *context* - контекст,
  *resource* - ID ресурса с разметкой для одного айтема в списке,  вида *R.layout.item*,
  *objects* - массив данных в виде объектов для отображения в списке.

`ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)`

- где:
  *context* - контекст,
  *resource* - ссылка на ресурс с разметкой для айтема вида *R.layout.item*,
  *textViewResourceId* - ID ресурса, указывающий на `TextView` в разметке айтема, в который будут выводиться данные, вида *R.id.textView*,
  *objects* - массив данных в виде объектов для отображения в списке.

`ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)`

- где:
  *context* - контекст,
  *resource* - ID ресурса с разметкой для одного айтема в списке,  вида *R.layout.item*,
  *objects* - коллекция данных для отображения.

`ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)`

- где:
  *context* - контекст,
  *resource* - ID ресурса с разметкой для одного айтема в списке,  вида *R.layout.item*,
  *textViewResourceId* - ID ресурса, указывающий на `TextView` в разметке айтема, в который будут выводиться данные, вида *R.id.textView*,
  *objects* - коллекция данных для отображения.

---

Внимательно осмотрев все это многообразие конструкторов, нетрудно убедится, что вам удалось составить такой конструктор, который программисты несчастного адаптера не предусмотрели.

В частности, **по вашему примеру:**

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.dialogs, R.id.listView, Dialogs);
```

*this* - служебное слово ссылается на экземпляр текущего объекта, в то время, как в конструкторе требуется контекст. `This` в качестве контекста может быть использовано только для активити, так как она является наследником контекста - для всех остальных классов контекст должен быть явным, в том числе и для вашего класса `Runnable`

*R.layout.dialogs* - будем надеяться, что это разметка **именно одного айтема** (одного элемента списка), хотя по выбранному для нее имени появляются сомнения

*R.id.listView* - третьим параметром должен быть указан ID `TextView` в айтеме (который должен находится  в разметке *R.layout.dialogs* в вашем случае), куда выводить данные, но никак **не ID всего списка** `ListView`.
Если в списке один `TextView` для отображения данных, то этот параметр лучше не указывать в конструкторе.

*Dialogs* - тоже неведомая сущность, на месте которой должен быть массив, либо коллекция данных, которую надо отобразить в списке. По имени похоже, что это какой то статический класс, так как начинается с заглавной буквы и если это так - этому классу в конструкторе не место.

Comment: Решением оказался такой код: ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
                                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(dialogs.this,
                                                                                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                                                                            Dialogs);

                                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Само забавное, что тот код который я давал вначале, был абсолютно верен)) так я и думал, если человек задает аналогичный вопрос, то проблема проще чем кажется. В любом случае ваше ответ +, за очень подробный разбор.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю в аргументах ошибка в **this**.

Вам нужно передать Context, а вы передаете Runnable объект.

Если код вызывается в активити (например в MainActivity), попробуйте вместо this передать MainActivity.this